# Dealing with each row as a separate message in biztalk?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

In other words, I am receiving multiple records from a stored procedure and I want to send each record in a separate message

Answer (score 0):

That's easily achievable using regular BizTalk Debatching.

This blog describes how to do that with the SQL Adapter, but any source will work the same.

[Debatching Inbound Messages From WCF SQL Adapter in BizTalk & Typed polling Debatching](http://btsguru.blogspot.com/2012/01/debatching-inbound-messages-from-wcf.html)

Keep in mind, debatching works the same Polling or Request/Response.